# Why I can't get the position of plane on the terrain with mouse click?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

What I have tried :

At the top of the script I added

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask terrainLayer;
```

In the Inspector I added a new layer at place 8 name Terrain then changed the Terrain layer to Terrain and also selected Terrain on this script in the terrainLayer variable.

Then in the SpawnThroughPlane method :

```
public void SpawnThroughPlane()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            //Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            var ray = new Ray(plane.transform.position, Vector3.down);

            //if (plane.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                cube = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);

                Vector3 pos = cube.transform.position;
                pos.y = terrain.SampleHeight(cube.transform.position);
                cube.transform.position = hit.point + pos;
            }
        }
    }
```

The result is when I click it's spawning objects no matter where I click with the mouse and show the objects at one position on same place.

[image: spawned objects not working as I wanted]

The full script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class SpawnObjects : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject prefabToSpawn;
    public Terrain terrain;
    public CustomPlane plane;
    public float yOffset = 0.5f;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask terrainLayer;

    private float terrainWidth;
    private float terrainLength;
    private float xTerrainPos;
    private float zTerrainPos;

    private float planeWidth;
    private float planeLength;
    private float xPlanePos;
    private float zPlanePos;

    private float yValTerrain;
    private float yValPlane;

    private float randXTerrain;
    private float randZTerrain;

    private float randXPlane;
    private float randZPlane;

    private Collider terrainCollider;
    void Awake()
    {
        if (terrain != null)
        {
            //Get terrain size
            terrainWidth = terrain.terrainData.size.x;
            terrainLength = terrain.terrainData.size.z;

            //Get terrain position
            xTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.x;
            zTerrainPos = terrain.transform.position.z;

            terrainCollider = terrain.GetComponent<Collider>();
        }

        if (plane != null)
        {
            planeWidth = plane.width;
            planeLength = plane.length;
            xPlanePos = plane.transform.position.x;
            zPlanePos = plane.transform.position.z;
        }
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        SpawnThroughPlane();
    }

    public void SpawnThroughPlane()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            //Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            var ray = new Ray(plane.transform.position, Vector3.down);

            //if (plane.GetComponent<MeshCollider>().Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity))
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, Mathf.Infinity, terrainLayer))
            {
                var prefab = Instantiate(prefabToSpawn);

                Vector3 pos = prefab.transform.position;
                pos.y = terrain.SampleHeight(prefab.transform.position);
                prefab.transform.position = hit.point + pos;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I want to do the same thing but instead the Input of the mousePosition to get the plane position" exactly?

Comment: @TackD. I mean that when I click the mouse right button I want it to spawn a cube on the terrain depending on the plane position.  The plane is above the terrain at some place so when I make right click with the mouse on the plane it should spawn a cube on that position on the terrain.  I will add another screenshot to show what I mean when the plane is above the terrain .

Comment: @TackD. It should spawn the cube only when making right click with the mouse on the plane and when the plane is above the terrain than to spawn a cube depending on the plane position.  It's like shooting the ray from the plane to the terrain.

Comment: Maybe the ray is shooting from the camera to the plane and never go thorugh the plane to the terrain ?

Comment: I want to drag the plane around over the terrain and when clicking the mouse button to get the position of the plane on the terrain instead the mouse position on the terrain.  It's almost the same but I want to use the plane as marker as visual where I click.

Comment: Well is the `plane.transform.position` in **screen (= PIXEL) space**? Because otherwise the usage of `ScreenPointToRay` makes not much sense ...

Comment: And yes also remove the planes collider or use a layermask to only hit the terrain and nothing else with the raycast

Comment: @derHugo it's not in screen space.  what should I use than instead ScreenPointToRay ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `plane.transform.position` is not in **screen (= PIXEL) space** the usage of `ScreenPointToRay` makes not much sense.

You probably rather want to simply use

```
var ray = new Ray(plane.transform.position, Vector3.down);
```

And as mentioned you should anyway make sure to use a `LayerMask` and only allow the raycast to hit the terrain by given it a dedicated [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) and select only that one in e.g.

```
[SerializeField] private LayerMask terrainLayer;
```

and then use

```
if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, Mathf.infinity, terrainLayer))
```

Comment: I tried it but it's not working. I will update my question with what I tried.

Comment: Updated my question with what I tried

Comment: Why do you do `prefab.transform.position = hit.point + pos;` ?